# Why does my reply appear as a normal comment instead of being a reply to the a particular comment?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make a reply function that will allow users to reply the comments but it is not able to display the reply as a child element . After getting posted it displays them as a normal comment.

Here,s the models.py for comments

```
class CommentManager(models.Manager):

    def all(self):
        qs = super(CommentManager,self).filter(parent = None)
        return qs

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name = "comments")
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField(default = True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self',null = True,blank = True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


    def replies(self):
        return  Comment.objects.filter(parent = self)


    @property
    def is_parent(self):
        if self.parent is not None:
            return False
        return True
```

Here, s the views.py of comments

```
def BlogDetail(request,pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk = pk) 
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    subscribe = Subscribe() 
    parent_obj = None



    if request.method  == 'POST':
        subscribe = Subscribe(request.POST) 
        comment = CommentForm(request.POST)


        if comment.is_valid():
            comment.instance.post = post
            comment.save()  

            try:
                parent_id = int(request.POST.get('parent_id'))
            except:
                parent_id = None

            if parent_id:
                parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id = parent_id)
                if parent_qs.exists():
                    parent_obj = parent_qs.first()  

        elif subscribe.is_valid():
            subscribe = subscribe.save(commit = True)



    return render(request,'app/blog.html',{'blog_object':post,'comment':comment,
        'subscribe':subscribe,'parent':parent_obj
        })
```

Here,s the html for comments and replies

```
{% for i in blog_object.get_comments %}
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col comment_head">
                                    <strong>{{i.name}}</strong>

                                    <div class="col comment_body">
                                        <p>{{i.body}}</p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>


                            <form action="." method="POST">

                                {% csrf_token %}

                                <div class="col">
                                    <div class="form-group form-group-with-icon">
                                        {{comment}}
                                        <div class="form-control-border"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  

                                <div class="col">
                                    <p class="form-submit">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="parent_id" id="parent_id" value="{{i.id}}">
                                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Reply Comment">
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                                {% for u in i.replies.all %}
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col comment_head">
                                    <strong>{{u.name}}</strong>

                                    <div class="col comment_body">
                                        <p>{{u.body}}</p>
                                    </div> 
                                </div>                          
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                            {% endfor %}

                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not there twice? With this code, I would expect to see the comment once as a reply and once at the top level.

Comment: Ya it, s at the top level but it should appear below the comment it was replied and when I check in the admin it has no parents